# Ansible error handling

Tags: ansible

Guys need one help with error, need to run one remote script on servers, but i get the below error.

my playbook

```
- hosts: broken
  strategy: debug
  become: yes
  remote_user: snehal

  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: check if file exists
      stat: path=/test/check_authkey
      register: authkey_exists

    - name: copying CEPLIVE script
      copy:
        src: /home/snehal/Final_build_files/check_authkey
        dest: /home/snehal/
      when: not authkey_exists.stat.exists

    - name: run  script
      command: /home/snehal/check_authkey.sh
      when: not authkey_exists.stat.exists
```

What does that error mean? how to check why is it failing?

```
PLAY [broken] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [check if file exists] ****************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [MOD009293]
ok: [MOD007479]

TASK [copying CEPLIVE script] **************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [MOD007479]
ok: [MOD009293]

TASK [run CEPLIVE script] ******************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [MOD007479]
fatal: [MOD009293]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["/home/snehal/check_authkey.sh"], "delta": "0:00:00.033337", "end": "2019-01-22 17:33:05.279549", "failed": true, "rc": 1, "start": "2019-01-22 17:33:05.246212", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/snehal/ansible/ceplive.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************************
MOD007479                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
MOD009293                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error means that your script `/home/snehal/Final_build_files/check_authkey` is running and exiting with a value of `1`.  Since you didn't share that script. I don't know why it exits with that value.

What happens if you run `/home/snehal/Final_build_files/check_authkey ; echo $?` manually on the remote?

If that exit code is not an error you can set a `failed_when` option for that task with a condition that describe what is and isn't a failure.

If it is a failure, you may need to debug your script.  In particular look at anything that references the environment.  The shell you get via ansible may have different PATH set, or other variables set differently.

Comment: Exit status is 1, but the script is running fine. is it possible to ignore that error? just blindly execute the script? ignore_errors: True